# Opencart how to test if module installed?

Tags: php, opencart

Is there a better way to check if a module has been installed in opencart. I am sure I must be missing something obvious for such a common task as this.

I want this to work in both the frontend (catalog) and admin area. This is the reason for checking if the method exists and if it is a multidimensional array.

```
$this->load->model('setting/extension');
$this->model_setting_extension = new ModelSettingExtension($this->registry);

if(method_exists($this->model_setting_extension, "getExtensions")){ 
    $extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getExtensions('module');
} else {
    $extensions = $this->model_setting_extension->getInstalled('module');
}   

$installed = false;
foreach($extensions as $extension){
    if(is_array($extension) && $extension['code'] == "myfoo"){
        $installed = true;
    } elseif($extension == "myfoo") {
        $installed = true;
    }
}
if(!$installed){
    exit('Error: Could not load module: myfoo!');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not elegant solution, but I did not find another

```
$module_name = 'bla-bla-module';
$this->load->model('setting/extension');
    $installed_modules = $this->model_setting_extension->getInstalled('module');
    if(in_array($module_name, $installed_modules)) {
      // Module installed
    }
```

UPD: this is for 1.5.x

Comment: This won't work on 2.0 as the model for `setting/extension` doesn't exist on the customer side, where as my solution works for 1.4.X right through to 2.X

Comment: Yes, you're right. I never used oc 2, just downloaded to see the difference :) Method getInstalled now in model/extension/extension.php so I guess we could change each 'setting' to 'extension' in the code above

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to simply check via a database query

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "extension` WHERE `code` = 'myfoo'");
if($result->num_rows) {
    // .. installed
} else {
    // .. not installed
}
```

Comment: I guess the 1 database query is better than my long winded method.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? (Source: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=49724)

```
<?php
    if ($this->config->get('modulename_status')) {
        // ....do something
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sadly not, I guess because it's not a standard module I am building it doesn't get loaded by opencart into the config automatically.

Comment: If it's a specific module, and you'd know the name of a function in it, you can do `if( function_exists("functionname") ) {...`

Comment: But it may still exist with being installed as a module yet.

Comment: Modules don't run on functions. They also don't always have a status